# How Qualtrics understands the response

Tags: web-services, qualtrics

I have implemented a web-service in qualtrics after a question block and the job is to do an operation and  send a response back to my website after the survey.I don't know how qualtrics record these responses. Is there any logs section in qualtrics where we can see these responses? Can we deal with the responses in the qualtrics login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're asking how responses are recorded in Qualtrics WebServices.

When a response comes in, Qualtrics parses the response as embedded data fields. Please note that the response has to be in json or xml encoding for Qualtrics to be able to properly parse it. When you test a webservice it gives you the option to set embedded data based on the response that comes back during testing.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Rivas for the help. I have seen that embedded data fields and was confused with it. Now you helped me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Qualtrics automatically parses your response and assigns it to each parameter.

Either way work. (I didn't test in xml but, I assume it would work as well)

1. `q1=answer1&q2=answer2&...`
2. in JSON `{"q1":"answer1", "q2":"answer2", ...)`